# Matrix representation from base $F$ to the standard base

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If I am given with some representation of a matrix $A$ in a base $F$, how do I show $A$'s representation in the standard base $E$?
Also, If I need to represent $A$ in some other base $G$, is there a direct way of getting a representation from $F$ to $G$ without using the standard base along the way?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you have two bases $E$ and $F$; it does not matter whether one of them is the "standard basis". What you need is the "change of basis matrix" from $E$ to $F$. This is a matrix M such that if you take a vector $V$, if you write its coordinates in the $E$ basis as a column vector denoted $V_E$, and if you compute the product $MV_E$, the result is the column vector $V_F$ which gives the coordinate of $V$ in the $F$ basis: $V_F = M V_E$. As a consequence, $V_E = M^{-1} V_F$.

So the answer to your question is that if $A$ is represented in the basis $F$ then $MAM^{-1}$ is the representation of in the basis $E$. I think of it this way:

- Start with any old column vector $V_F$ written in $F$-coordinates.
- Convert to $E$-coordinates:  $M^{-1} V_F$
- Apply the matrix $A$: $A M^{-1} V_F$
- Convert back to $F$-coordinates: $MAM^{-1} V_F$
- Conclusion: $MAM^{-1}$ is the representation of $A$ in $E$-coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

In both cases, you conjugate by a change of basis matrix.

If $F$ is a base and $v$ is a vector, I'll denote the vector $v$ with coefficients relative to $F$ as $[v]_F$. Then if $G = \{g_1, g_2, \ldots, g_n\}$, let $$S = \left(\begin{array}{cccc} [g_1]_F & [g_2]_F & \ldots & [g_n]_F\end{array}\right).$$ It is clear that $S$ has the property that $S[v]_G = [v]_F$ for any vector $v$ (just check the basis vectors). Thus, to get the matrix of the same linear transformation, but now with respect to the basis $G$, we just multiply $$S^{-1}AS.$$ Note that this works for switching to the standard base by taking $G=E$ and computing $S$ the same way as above.